# How to get the LENDDO score from REST API in PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

How to get the LENDDO score from REST API in PHP 
My client id = LEDEMO1070168781157742500 
For above client_id my Lenddo Score is 480, which is display on my Lenddo dashboard but not getting this score via API. 
Not Share my API and secret key. 
Basically i need the help for generating AUTHORIZATION HEADER which I perform in the signRequest() function. 
The reference  = https://www.lenddo.com/documentation/rest_api.html

```
/*
<?php
$method = "GET";
$date = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
$url = '/ClientScore/LEDEMO1070168781157742500'; 

function signRequest($method, $body, $date, $url) { 
$api = '';       //my api key
$secret = '';    // my secret key 
$contentMd5 = NULL;
if( !empty( $body ) ) { 
    $contentMd5 = md5( $body );
}
$stringToSign = $method . "\n" . $contentMd5 . "\n" . $date . "\n" . $url; 
$string = "LENDDO " . $api . ":"; 



$string .= base64_encode(
    hash_hmac( "sha1", $stringToSign, $secret, TRUE )
);
return $string; 
}
$val = signRequest('GET', '', $date, $url);  // get the access token



 $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://scoreservice.lenddo.com/ClientScore/LEDEMO1070168781157742500");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $val);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
// the above source code gives me the output => string(141) "{"message": "Signature generated from request data does not match the signature provided in the Authorization Header.", "name": "FORBIDDEN"} "
// i pass my api and secret key into the code above but got this error, help me to find Lenddo Score.
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the lead developer here at Lenddo. It seems you're taking the difficult route to integration. Thankfully for PHP (5.3+) we actually provide a SDK which should make integration fairly painless.

You can find the PHP SDK here: https://github.com/Lenddo/php-lenddo. On this page is the README where you can find the table of contents, and more specifically [installation instructions](https://github.com/Lenddo/php-lenddo#installation).

Since you're trying to retrieve the score you can use the [REST Service Client](https://github.com/Lenddo/php-lenddo/blob/master/docs/service_client.md). On this page you'll find instructions on retrieving a score.

To help you get jumpstarted I'll provide a summarized list of instructions here (as it stands today):

1. [Install composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)
2. Perform the following command: `composer require lenddo/sdk`
3. Paste the following code snippet in an empty PHP file:

```php
<?php

// Fill out the ID & Secret provided to you by your contact at Lenddo.
$id = '';
$secret = '';

// Require the Composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiate the Lenddo Service Client
$client = new Lenddo\ServiceClient( $id, $secret );

// Replace the APPLICATION_ID with your client/application ID
// Replace the PARTNER_SCRIPT_ID with your partner script id
$response = $client->applicationScore('APPLICATION_ID', 'PARTNER_SCRIPT_ID');

// Get the Status Code for the response
$status_code = $response->getStatusCode(); // 200

// Retrieve the body of the response
$score_results = $response->getBody();

// Return the score value and reason flags.
$score_value = $score_results->score;
$score_flags = $score_results->flags;

echo $score_value;
```

4. Follow all of the in-line comments for the code sample provided.